# Stuck on scraping data from third frame

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm not a pro just trying to scrape some data from a website.
Some one from here helped me to select first "frame" but I need to scrape data from third frame and concatenate data from frame 1 + frame 2 + frame 3 in just one result.This is the site 
This is what I have:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let scrape = async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        slowMo: 250
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('', {
        waituntil: "networkidle0"
    });
    const frame = await page.frames().find(f => f.name() === 'stanga');
    const button = await frame.$('body > form > font > select > option:nth-child(12)');
    button.click();
    await page.waitFor(1000);
    const frame1 = await page.frames().find(a => a.name() ==='centru');
    const select = await frame1.$('body > form > font > select > option:nth-child(1)');
    await page.waitFor(500);
    select.click();
    await page.waitFor(500);

    const result = await page.$$eval("body > font", (options) => {
        const timpi = options.map(option => option.innerText);

        return timpi

    });

    await browser.close();
    return result;
};
scrape().then((value) => {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed our script:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let scrape = async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto('http://example.com/txt', { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
const optionSelector = 'body > form > font > select > option';
const frames = await page.frames();
const expectedFrames = ['stanga', 'centru'];
const scrapedText = [];


const getOptions = (frameName) => { 
  return frameName.$$eval(optionSelector, (options) => {
    const result = options.map(option => option.innerText);

    return result;
  }, optionSelector);
}

for (const frame of frames) {
  const name = frame.name();

  if (expectedFrames.includes(name)) {
    await frame.click(optionSelector);
    await page.waitFor(1000);
    const result = await getOptions(frame);

    scrapedText.push({[name]: result});
  } else if (name === 'dreapta') {
    const result = await frame.$eval('body', elm =>  elm.innerText);

    scrapedText.push({[name]: result.split(/\n+/g)});
  }
}


await browser.close();

return scrapedText;
};

scrape().then((value) => {
  console.log(value); 
});
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[{ 
   stanga: ['Mures','A Saguna', 'A.Guttenbrun_1', ... and more items]
 },
 {
   centru: ['[0] E3'] 
 },
 { 
   dreapta: ['Linia: E3','2019-07-25 23:19:40','Sosire1: 23:39','Sosire2: 23:41'] 
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to improve your scraper not just to click on the select, but also to pull selected item value from the select object.

```
  const frame = await page.frames().find(f => f.name() === "stanga");
  const select1 = await frame.$(
    "body > form > font > select > option:nth-child(12)"
  );

  const select1Value = await frame.evaluate(
    select1 => select1.textContent,
    select1
  );
```

select1Value will have the value of the selected item in select box. The same must be done for select2 in the next frame.

In your code, you don't select frame3, thats why you cannot read data from it.

I have updated your code and this is the result I could get out of your code:

```
$ node scrape.js
Frame1: AT_Miresei_1
Frame2:  [1]  E1
Frame3: Linia: E12019-07-25 22:29:13Sosire1: 22:55 Sosire2: 23:00
```

This is what I ended up with, but there is a lot to improve (code quality and readability).

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

let scrape = async () => {
  let result;

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("http://ratt.ro/txt", {
    waituntil: "networkidle0"
  });

  // Frame 1
  const frame = await page.frames().find(f => f.name() === "stanga");
  const button = await frame.$(
    "body > form > font > select > option:nth-child(12)"
  );

  const select1Value = await frame.evaluate(
    button => button.textContent,
    button
  );

  button.click();
  await page.waitFor(1000);

  // Frame 2
  const frame1 = await page.frames().find(a => a.name() === "centru");
  const select = await frame1.$(
    "body > form > font > select > option:nth-child(1)"
  );

  const select2Value = await frame1.evaluate(
    select => select.textContent,
    select
  );

  await page.waitFor(200);
  select.click();

  await page.waitFor(200);

  // Frame 3
  const frame3 = await page.frames().find(f => f.name() === "dreapta");
  const element = await frame3.$("body");
  const frame3Text = await frame3.evaluate(
    element => element.textContent,
    element
  );

  await browser.close();

  result =
    "Frame1: " +
    select1Value +
    "\nFrame2: " +
    select2Value +
    "\nFrame3: " +
    frame3Text.trim();

  return result;
};

scrape().then(value => {
  console.log(value);
});
```